# Copying files from subfolders to one folder based on a list in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two files which are in two different subfolders. Please refer to the screengrab below:

[image: Screen Grabo of filename and Path]

Currently, I am using the following macro to copy files from one folder to another based on the list of files in the excel(all these files are in one folder) but it does not allow copying files from subfolders:

```
Sub copyfiles()
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
    Dim xVal As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "KuTools For Excel", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = "Please select the original folder:"

    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = "Please select the destination folder:"

    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"

    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value

        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If I use the same macros for files which are in 2 subfolders I get file not found error.
So is there a way I modify the same macro to allow me to copy files from subfolders?

Comment: First of all remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line just hides **all** error messages, but the errors still occur. You just cannot see them (so you are blind for errors). You cannot fix errors that you cannot see. Never use that line without proper error handling ([VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)). • Remove it and fix your errors instead (If you don't know how, include the error message and where the error occurs in your question above).

Comment: What is happening now?  Not sure i get what you are after?

Comment: I removed it and it gives me file not found error

Comment: refer to my edits @Nathan_Sav

Comment: Still unsure.  Are you saying that if the user selects `c:\folder1` and the file isnt in there, search `c:\folder1\subfolder1\`?

Comment: Refer to my screenshot. If I just select 5 as my original folder thinking that it should copy both the files from the subfolders it does not, that is what I want that it should copy files from subfolders. hope this helps